# show that there exists a set with $x_{1},.....,x_{n}$ as its elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x_{1},....,x_{n}$ be sets for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n\ge 1$.

a) show that there exist a set with $x_{1},....,x_{n}$ as its elements

b)show that $x_{1}\cup x_{2}\cup...\cup x_{n}$ is a set.

My first thought was to do it like that

we can form a set $\{x_{1},x_{2}\}$ which is a set by axiom of pairs and a set $\{x_{n}\}$

then 
$\{x_{1},x_{2}\}\cup \{x_{n}\}$ is also a set by the union axiom but $\{x_{1},x_{2}\}\cup \{x_{n}\}=\{x_{1},x_{2},...x_{n}\}$

is this okay as the answer to a)?

what should be done in b)?

I know that for example $x_{1}\cup x_{2}:=\bigcup\{x_{1},x_{2}\}$

does it mean that

$x_{1}\cup....\cup x_{n}=\bigcup\{x_{1},....,x_{n}\}$

but how to show that this is a set?

Comment: What about $x_3 \in \{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\}$? (You may want to use induction to do part a. rigorously.)

Comment: @Lord_Farin You are of course rigth, but in my opinion you can't really do something rigorously if it uses "$\ldots$" already in the problem statement

Answer (score 1):

For part b) all you need to do is use the set you obtain from part a) and apply the union axiom to it to prove $\bigcup\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ is a set.